# Битрикс. Код ответа 200 при недоступной базе. Кто решал подобную проблему?

Tags: php, битрикс

Достался "проект отличного качества". Смесь битрикса и самописного кода.
Нашел похожий [вопрос](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic122483/), но ответа нет.
Пытаюсь понять.
Это проблема битрикса в принципе или это результат кастомных изменений поверх?
Пока мысль полезть в драйвер подключения к базе и там как то отлавливать.

1С-Битрикс: Управление сайтом 19.0.700

Comment: Пока похоже на то, что страница у вас доступна, отсюда и статус 200, а при недоступной БД ошибка не обрабатывается в том смысле, чтобы выводить 500 - Internal Server Error или ещё что-то в том же роде. Больше похоже на кастомные настройки при подключении к БД, но это не точно. ))

Comment: А в чём, собственно, состоит проблема? Вы хотите, чтобы сайт падал?

Answer (score 0):

При всех ошибках с подключением к базе данных битрикс бросает исключение типа Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException. Её можно ловить и обрабатывать.

Если не предпринять специальных мер, то ошибка подключения возникнет при инициализации ядра, до того как будут подключены компоненты и шаблоны сайта, и там же будет обработана.

Поэтому где-то в начале /local/php_interface/init.php добавляем следующие строки:

```php
try {
    \Bitrix\Main\UserTable::getRow([]);
} catch (\Bitrix\Main\DB\ConnectionException $e) {
    ... а тут делаем нужную обработку ...
    die();
}
```

То есть пробуем прочитать любую строку из таблицы юзеров, а если возникает ошибка подключения, то обрабатываем её.